# Run additional build scripts as part of angular build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular application that loads an iframe and the iframe is a basic html page (`iframe.html`) and a Vanilla JavaScript file (`iframe.js`). I have put these 2 files in the `assets` folder so that they simply get copied to the `dist` folder when the application is built. And on the index.html I am importing it as

```
<iframe src="assets/iframe.html"></iframe>
```

All this works fine but now I want to convert the `iframe.js` file to typescript.

Now coming to building the iframe files and the application, I can have a separate `tsconfig.json` for it and run `tsc iframe.ts && ng build`.

But now assume someone new to the project just runs `ng build`, then the iframe won't get built.

Is there any way to modify the `ng build` script so that it also runs `tsc iframe.ts` taking  into account its own `tsconfig.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify in `pacakge.json` what `ng build` does, however, you can add a `prebuild` option to run before each npm task. These suffixes can be added to any NPM script and will run automatically when you run the main script. e.g.:

`npm run build`

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prebuild": "tsc iframe.ts",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

Albeit yes, that's no longer shorthand CLI command `ng build`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can achieve this by modifying the **Angular build process** to include the **TypeScript compilation** for our iframe.ts file along with the main application build.

To do this, we can use the Angular workspace configuration file (**angular.json**) and leverage the **"builder" property** to customize the build process.

Create a new **tsconfig file** for the iframe:
In the root of our Angular project, create a new tsconfig.iframe.json file with the TypeScript configuration for our iframe.ts.

**tsconfig.iframe.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "outDir": "src/assets",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/assets/iframe.ts"
  ]
}
```

Update **angular.json** to include the iframe build:
Open the angular.json file and locate the projects.architect.build.options section.
In this section, we'll find the build options for our main Angular application.
Add a new configuration to include the iframe TypeScript compilation.

Example **angular.json**:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "our-angular-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
           
          },
          "configurations": {
            "iframe": { // Add a new configuration for the iframe build
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.iframe.json",
              "assets": [
                
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I added the configuration as suggested but running ng build wasn't picking up this new configuration. So I tried running `ng build --configuration iframe` but that doesn't seem to work either. I am getting the error `src\main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.`. Is it supposed to work automatically by just adding the configuration or am I missing something?